# git doesn't work behind proxy since version 1.7.9

Tags: git, proxy

Since git 1.7.9 I haven't been able to clone, fetch, or push to repositories through a proxy server. It works well with version 1.7.8, but newer versions, including the latest version, throw this error:

```
error: Failure when receiving data from the peer while accessing http://github.com/...
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have set http.proxy property in git config, which was sufficient in 1.7.8. The only way I was able to get newer versions of git running was to use cntlm.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Good job on giving enough information for people to help you out.  In the future, you can tab (four spaces) in any code or I/O to draw attention to the important parts! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am cloning with git1.7.9+ (recently 1.8+) behind proxy.

I don't, however, set http.proxy in the *git* configuration.
I do, on Windows or Unix, set the environment variables:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.fr.domain:80/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.fr.domain:80/
NO_PROXY=*.domain
```

And I clone/push/pull GitHub repos without any issue.

Comment: @VonC - should I add these in the Path variable? Or should I add them as separate variables like JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @LohithKrishna Those are separate (user) environment variables, like `JAVA_HOME`. They are not related to the `PATH`.